# Split is not working in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Split function is not working in IE9

Here is my code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var currURL = window.location.href;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var hasFilters = currURL.split('?')[1];
            alert(hasFilters);    
            if (hasFilters) {
                abc(currURL);
            }
        });
</script>
```

When I am running this script in IE9 at that time, in alert showing "undefined" while at other browser in alert shows concate string for currurl for ex : `"abc=def:ijk!!a!!"`.

So I want to do same in IE9.

Maybe somebody can point me to the right answer?
Thx

Comment: Are you sure the url is same as in other browsers? because AFAIK, split works fine in all browsers.

Comment: You are placing blame in the wrong location. if `split` truely was the problem, you would be able to recreate this with a test string.

Answer (score -1):

**Better yet: window.location object has search property which is what you're trying to find.**

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

`window.location.search`: Sets or returns the querystring part of a URL

**Why [1] might not be working...**

This is working in IE for me here as long as you have `?x=y` at the end. `split` returns an array and for an index that doesn't exist you will get undefined. Let's look at two test cases:

```
window.location.href: index.html?x=y
split: 'index.html', 'x=y'
[0] = index.html
[1] = x=y

window.location.href: index.html
split: 'index.html'
[0] = index.html
[1] (etc) = undefined
```

I think the issue is that in IE you're not including the ? part of the URL. I doubt it is a bug in the browser.

Comment: Not an answer. You just showed that split works fine. _we know that_

Comment: I think the OP is trying to get the query string from the URL, so I updated my answer with `window.location.search`. My answer is that '?' must be missing, so showing that split works fine is my rationale for that theory.